# html space re-sizing - under Accordion

Tags: html, css

I am using an Accordion on my web page. When I click on the Accordion it expands downward and creates new space. I would like to add something below my Accordion, maybe a `<div>`. I want the `<div>` height to be a specified size, but then get shorter when one of the Accordions are opened. And I want this to work well with my responsive website.

```
<div class="Accordion-box">
 Accordion Code

 <div class="Accordion-spacer">
  This get shorter when an Accordion opens up.
 </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciative.

Comment: Can you include your JS code as well, possibly even a jsfiddle?

Comment: You know what, I'm using WordPress, and I am using a plugin and outputting Shortcode to get the Accordion Code. But the Accordion is only using HTML & CSS. I was able to duplicate the Accordion code with just HTML & CSS without using the plugin. Do you think I need to use JS or jsfiddle?

Comment: If you can get it to work in a fiddle, I'd say go that route.